# How can I call cleanup manually after a bolt is finished in apache storm?

Tags: apache-storm

Can I call cleanup manually after I am done with some task in my bolt? Lets say clear a hash which I am using in the code after I am finished processing a set of input?

Also is there a way to trigger a run of whole topology on getting an event? For example if I am reading from a message queue and just got a new message, how do I enforce another run for the topology? Will I need to create a new topology now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the answer, a warning. It isn't necessarily safe to assume only one starting tuple is going through your topology at a time, search for documentation for the [MaxSpoutPending](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html) parameter.

In order to clean up your data you have a few options, the first is to use [Coordination](http://www.pixelmachine.org/storm/2012/01/03/How-CoordinatedBolt-Works.html), this will trigger a callback on each bolt when it has ack'ed all of the incoming tuples for a given starting tuple.

If all you are doing is clearing a cache, we use a [Guava Cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) with an expiry timeout equal to, or a bit greater than, the messageTimeoutSecs setting. Basically the cache clears itself after enough time has passed that the original tuple has either finished processing or timed out

Comment: Thank you for the response. But still how to a trigger a new run for the topology? So lets say my spout is fetching data from a queue. Is there a way I can start the topology once I have data in the queue? Will I have to create a new topology if I get new data once my earlier processing has finished?

Comment: The topology is always running. When the spout has something to emit, it will; any bolts subscribed to the spout's stream will execute and, if they emit, any bolts subscribed to them will execute in turn, etc. A topology processes a never ending stream of events, in your case the items arriving on the queue